# Selenium SendKey conflict with jquery inputmask

Tags: c#, selenium, jquery-inputmask

I am using C# `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects` and `OpenQA.Selenium`.

In the page model, I tried to enter an email to the textbox which has an inputmask.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Email")]
private IWebElement _txtEmail;

public string Email
{
    set
    {
        _txtEmail.SendKeys(value);
    }
}
```

Then after SendKey, I got something like this screenshot.
[image]

What is the correct way to SendKeys when there is an input mask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here, in many cases Selenium is entering the data faster than the JavaScript can process it causing weird behavior.  The best bet is to click the element first, than wait a second.  Then start entering the data.

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

If that still does not work, you may want to consider injecting JavaScript directly to then populate the text input's value.

---

## Update

Here is the working code snippet:

```
public string Email
{
    set
    {
        _txtEmail.Click();
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        _txtEmail.SendKeys(value);
    }
}
```

No need to wait for 1000ms.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I wait a second?

Comment: I used `Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));`. still messed input mask.

Comment: make you you click the element first, allowing time for the mask to fire, than sleep, than enter data, if that does not work look to use javascript to inject the value.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the ideal solution but it just worked.

NuGet a package called `Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium`.

And use this following code snippet to take the place of `SendKeys()`

```
public string Email
{
    set
    {
        var selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, MyPageUrl);
        selenium.Start();
        selenium.Type("Email", value);
    }
}
```

But there must be a better way for this. Let's post this here as a makeshift solution while waiting for a better answer.